# Pywin32 with Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, windows-services, pywin32

With reference to the article regarding Pywin32 windows service ([Python win32 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499859/python-win32-service)), I'm new to Python and I wanted to build a windows service in python. The above given article was so helpful. I'm using Python2.7 with Eclipse and installed pywin32-217.win32-py2.7. When I copied the code and executed it worked fine but all the imported modules appear underlined in red color saying Unresolved import (But it works). Could anyone please be kind enough to help me with this and could you please tell me if eclipse supports code autocompletion for Pywin32. If it is yes, please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

Make sure your `[python root]/Lib/site-packages/win32` is in your `System PYTHONPATH` in your interpreter-setup (window -> preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python).
That should give you full auto-completion and let Eclipse recognize your win32 imports.

Hope this helps.